# Unable to obtain chrome runtime in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to test an extension using Puppeteer. While Puppeteer shouldn't have `chrome.runtime`, on evaluating the automated browser `runtime` is also not available on Chromium as well.

The reason I ask this is because I can't use chrome because it doesn't allow loading of extensions using `--disable-extensions-except`. Any workaround this?

Again this question goes back to extension invocation using puppeteer. I was wondering if there is a way around this?